# Как поставить названия категорий из БД в таблице?

Tags: php

Собственно, суть: есть таблица БД, со столбцами айди юзера/категории/товары. На личной странице каждого юзера выводится таблица с выборкой из БД внесенных им товаров (типа яблоко, арбуз, груша, помидор, творог). Хотелось бы, чтобы они шли не просто перечислением а разделенные названиями категорий, например:
/фрукты/
яблоки
груши
/овощи/
помидор
и т.п.
причем, если в какой-то категории у юзера ничего нет, ее в таблицу просто не надо вставлять (чтобы не было пустой категории без товара). На данный момент код с выборкой такой:

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, kats, name FROM characters WHERE account = $myrow2[id] ORDER BY name");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$table["id"]."' >".$table["kats"].", ".$table["name"]."</option>";
}
?>
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы добавились нужные категории подзаголовками и список по ним рассортировался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему [GROUP BY kats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) либо [ORDER BY kats, name](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/182)

А в цикле, наверно, в начале поставить "`if (empty($table['kats'])) continue;`"

**Добавлено:**

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, kats, name FROM characters WHERE account = {$myrow2['id']} ORDER BY kats, name");
$Products = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  if (empty($row->kats)) continue;
  if (!isset($Products[$row->kats]))
    $Products[$row->kats] = array();
  $Products[$row->kats][] = array('id'=>$row->id, 'name'=>$row->name);
  }

foreach($Products as $category_name => $items) {
  echo '<option> '.$category_name.'</option>';
  foreach ($items as $item)
    echo '<option value="'.$item['id'].'">-- '.$item['name'].'</option>';
  }
?>
```

Как-то так)

Comment: order by - да, вывел их по категориям и после в алфавитном порядке. но названий категорий, по которым выводит, автоматом не добавил =/
или я что-то не туда дописала =/ можно поточнее, куда if... вставлять?

Comment: Названия категорий надо получать отдельно и я не знаю структуру вашей БД, чтобы это написать. Через час-два появлюсь, попробую в общем виде наваять, а пока напишите поля таблицы с товарами и с категориями.

Comment: Табличка (characters): id, kats, name  . id - это айди юзера, в kats записываются категории, в name - конкретные названия всяких овощей/фруктов. Каждая строчка, таким образом, выглядит так:  1 овощи помидор  1 овощи огурец  1 фрукты яблоко  5 овощи огурец  3 фрукты яблоко  3 фрукты груша  
Названия берутся напрямую из обработчика формы ввода (там они просто перечислены и выбираются селектом). Отдельной таблицы под категории нет, хотя если нужно будет - могу создать.

Comment: Проверьте плиз, обновил.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно=)